# c++ winapi impossible to create 2 controls

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, listbox, richedit

I'm trying to create window that contain richedit control and listbox control,
the problem is that the second control which I create, doesn't show up.
I mean:

```
case WM_CREATE: // In main window procedure
{
    /* Center the main window */
    This->CenterWindow(hwnd);

    /* Initialize the clients list */
    This->InitListClients(hwnd);

    /* Initialize the server log */
    This->InitEditLog(hwnd);

    return 0;
}
```

If `InitListClients` function will be first, only the listbox will show up,
if `InitEditLog` will be first, only the richedit will show up.

Here are the functions:

```
void ApostleServer::InitEditLog(HWND &_hwnd)
{
    LoadLibrary(TEXT("Riched32.dll"));
    hEditLog = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, "richedit", "bla", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE, 10, 10, 390, 310, _hwnd, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(_hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
}

void ApostleServer::InitListClients(HWND &_hwnd)
{
    hListClients = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, "listbox", "bla", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_NOTIFY, 550, 20, 150, 150, _hwnd, NULL, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(_hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
}
```

I'm kinda newbie with winapi and I couldn't find solution for this problem.
Thanks.

EDIT:
As I commented, the cause of the problem is the use of class members.
Here is a whole code that I've wrote and has the same problem:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Server
{
public:

    /* Fields */
    MSG* msg;
    WNDCLASSW* wc;
    HWND hListClients;
    HWND hEditLog;

    /* Methods */
    void InitEditLog(HWND &_hwnd)
    {
        LoadLibrary(TEXT("Riched32.dll"));
        hEditLog = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, L"richedit", L"Text", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE, 10, 10, 390, 306, _hwnd, (HMENU)2, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(_hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
    }

    void InitListClients(HWND &_hwnd)
    {
        // Here I'm using hListClients class member, and that what cause the problem (I will see only the list on the window)
        hListClients = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, L"listbox", L"asd", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_NOTIFY, 410, 10, 160, 306, _hwnd, (HMENU)1, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(_hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
        // If I was only creating the listbox (without returning handler), I will see the listbox and the richedit.
    }

    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {

        Server* This = (Server*)GetWindowLongW(hwnd, GWL_USERDATA);

        switch(msg)
        {
            case WM_CREATE:
            {
                /* Initialize the clients list */
                This->InitListClients(hwnd); // Attention that I called this function first.

                /* Initialize the server log */
                This->InitEditLog(hwnd);
                // If I would call this function first, I will see only the richedit.

                return 0;
            }

            case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
            }
        }

        return DefWindowProcW(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    Server(HINSTANCE &_hInstance)
    {
        msg = new MSG;
        wc = new WNDCLASSW;
        wc->style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wc->cbClsExtra = 0;
        wc->cbWndExtra = 0;
        wc->lpszClassName = L"ApostleServer";
        wc->hInstance = _hInstance;
        wc->hbrBackground = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_3DFACE);
        wc->lpszMenuName = NULL;
        wc->lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
        wc->hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wc->hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

        RegisterClassW(&(*wc));
        CreateWindowW(wc->lpszClassName, L"Apostle Server", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 600, 400, 0, 0, _hInstance, 0);

        while(GetMessage(&(*msg), NULL, 0, 0))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&(*msg));
            DispatchMessage(&(*msg));
        }

    }
};

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    Server* srvr = new Server(hInstance);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first block of code is rather strange. First of all, the `this` pointer is not capitalized in C++. So I assume that's the name of a variable that points to a C++ object representing the window. But then why would you be passing the window handle as a parameter, rather than accessing it as a member variable? Anyway, not what's breaking your code, just something to puzzle over.

Comment: Another problem is that you're using 8-byte ANSI strings, despite it being the year 2013. All Windows applications should be Unicode now. Make sure that the `UNICODE` symbol is defined, and that your string literals are prefixed with `L`.

Comment: The code works fine for me, though. So the problem lies in something other than what you've shown us here. You can debug this for yourself by creating a new project and adding pieces of your code back in one at a time.

Comment: Well, changing the strings to unicode solved my problem, but one question, is there a `CreateWindow` function that receive unicode strings and has extended style?

Comment: CreateWindowEx is what it's called.

Comment: `CreateWindowExW` - thought it doesn't exists.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yup. The `W` suffix will be added automatically if `UNICODE` is defined for your project. Which it should be, to ensure that the compiler catches errors.

Comment: After compiling the code it works fine, so your pb is probably elsewhere.

Comment: Oops, stupid me - changing to UNICODE didn't solved my problem, (I checked the code on another project and it worked fine), but I solved it by place the call to the functions after I create the main window and not when I get WM_CREATE message, I don't realy know what the difference but problem solved, so.. :)

Comment: I found out why it happens in WM_CREATE. I don't know how to solve it though.
If I use one of my class members (with `This` pointer that I created) the `CreateWindow` functions doesn't work. I don't know the logic behind it, so I'm still stuck over here.

Comment: I have no idea, I can't see the code that you're using. I don't know what this statement means: *"If I use one of my class members (with This pointer that I created) the CreateWindow functions doesn't work."* Use the [edit] link to add [a self-contained sample](http://sscce.org/) to your question.

Comment: @CodyGray Edited, if you want to watch at the original project code, here you go: http://ohadp.no-ip.org/ApostleProject/ApostleServer/ApostleServer/Server.cpp

Comment: I have one solution but I think it's not effective,
I can use `GetDlgItem`, but every time I'll want to handle some control, I'll have to create new `HWND` object, what do you think about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by creating the controls on `WM_CREATE` message (but not to set control handlers!), and set the control handlers after the creation of the main window.

`WM_CREATE` message:

```
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        /* Center the main window */
        This->CenterWindow(hwnd);

        /* Initialize the clients list */
        This->InitListClients(hwnd);

        /* Initialize the server log */
        This->InitEditLog(hwnd);


        return 0;
    }
```

After main window creation:

```
RegisterClassW(&(*wc));
hMainWindow = CreateWindowW(wc->lpszClassName, L"Apostle Server", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 100, 100, 600, 400, 0, 0, _hInstance, 0);

/* Set controls handlers */
hListClients = GetDlgItem(hMainWindow, IDC_LISTCLIENTS);
hEditLog = GetDlgItem(hMainWindow, IDC_EDITLOG);
```

`InitEditLog` and `InitListClients` functions:

```
void ApostleServer::InitEditLog(HWND &_hwnd)
{
    LoadLibrary(TEXT("Riched32.dll"));
    CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, L"richedit", L"Text", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | ES_MULTILINE, 10, 10, 390, 306, _hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_EDITLOG, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(_hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
}

void ApostleServer::InitListClients(HWND &_hwnd)
{
    CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_STATICEDGE, L"listbox", L"asd", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_NOTIFY, 410, 10, 160, 306, _hwnd, (HMENU)IDC_LISTCLIENTS, (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(_hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
}
```