# Window creation fails with non-NULL hMenu parameter

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface, createwindow

In addition to the main window, I'm trying to create another top level window. The problem is that when I'm setting the second window's `hMenu` parameter to a non-NULL value, it doesn't show up.

e.g:

This window shows up (hMenu == 0)

```
case IDC_BUTTON_SEND_COMMAND:
{
    CreateWindowExW(NULL,
                    L"CommandWindow", L"Send Command",
                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
                    100, 100, 600, 400,
                    NULL,
                    (HMENU)0,
                    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
    break;
}
```

This window doesn't show up (hMenu == 4)

```
case IDC_BUTTON_SEND_COMMAND:
{
    CreateWindowExW(NULL,
                    L"CommandWindow", L"Send Command",
                    WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
                    100, 100, 600, 400,
                    NULL,
                    (HMENU)4,
                    (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE), NULL);
    break;
}
```

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: `GetWindowLong` is not compatible with 64bit OSs. Use [`GetWindowLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585.aspx) instead, that can be used for both 32 and 64bit code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing `(HMENU)4` as the `hMenu` parameter to [`CreateWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx) to create a top level window tells the system to attach a menu to it. This menu has the menu handle 4. A menu handle (`HMENU`) is returned from functions like [`CreateMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647624.aspx). If the handle is not a valid `HMENU` window creation fails.

Your observation, that the window *doesn't show up* is misleading yourself into believing that the window actually exists. The window doesn't exist, and `CreateWindowEx` returns `NULL`. Checking return values is advisable, and calling [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms679360.aspx) when an API call fails is usually quite helpful.

Comment: Alright. but I'm using the hMenu parameter so I will be able to access the different controls handlers by their control ID (hMenu), I don't realy need a menu on my window, and empty menus are not allowed. any solution?

Comment: @user The `hMenu` parameter has an overloaded meaning: If you create a **top level** window it designates the ID of the menu resource. If you create a **child window** it is the ID of the control. A child window is a window that has the `WS_CHILD` window style, a top level window does not. Control ID's are assigned to distinguish between different child windows sharing the same parent. For this reason it does not make sense to assign a control ID to a top level window. A top level window can be identified by its `HWND`.

Comment: OK, got it, now I've got some problem that prevent me from making the window top level window, therefore I need to make it child and popup window, but according to microsoft reference the use of `WS_CHILD` and `WS_POPUP` is not allowed, what should I do?

Comment: @user You can create multiple top level windows passing a `NULL` parameter as the `hMenu`/control ID. There is no requirement that this value must be unique. If you need to interact with those windows you have the `HWND` returned by `CreateWindowEx`. If you have other requirements that prevent you from making those windows top level windows you should start I would suggest to start a new question to keep question and answers focused on a single topic.

Comment: Correction to my comment above: For a top level window the `HMENU` parameter designates a menu **handle**, not a menu **resource ID**.

Comment: You say "I'm using the hMenu parameter so I will be able to access the different controls handlers by their control ID (hMenu)". I don't understand what that means. What control handlers are you talking about? Do you mean the window procedure for the top level window?

Comment: I'm creating the window in the main window procedure, and it's impossible to put the handler in my class member - [realy long story](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419563/c-winapi-impossible-to-create-2-controls), so after I create the main window, I get all the controls handlers that I created in WM_CREATE event by their control ID.

Comment: Ok, I read the "really long story" and now I understand that when you say "control handlers", you mean "control handles". I think you are planning to use GetDlgItem to get the handles to the CommandWindows you create, but GetDlgItem will only return the handles for windows that are children of some other window (not top level windows). So why do you want the CommandWindows to be top level windows? By the way, you doing this the hard way, I don't know C++ (I use C) so I don't know why you are having a problem storing the control handles in class members, but I am sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Your window fails creation because (HMENU)4 is *not* a valid menu *handle*, such as those returned from CreateMenu() or LoadMenu().

(HMENU)4 would be a valid *control ID*, if the window was a child window.
MAKEINTRESOURCE(4) would also be a valid menu *resource ID*, if specified in the WNDCLASS[EX] struct when you register your class with RegisterClass[Ex].

You need to specify a valid menu *handle* if you want to use the hMenu parameter of CreateWindow[Ex] when you create a *top level window*.

A menu handle can be acquired either using an API like CreateMenu(), or by loading a menu resource, f.ex with LoadMenu( GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(4) ).

Hope that helps.